# Key-Value in SharePoint List column

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, managed-metadata, calculated-column-formula, key-filter

I would like to add in a column some key-values choice (multiple or not)

```
KEY1 : "Short description 1"
KEY2 : "Short description 2"
KEY3 : "Short description 3"
```

saved value should be the key, but the displayed - both key and description (at least when selecting the value)

I started to use Managed Metadata, because there is easy to centralised manage the list of values, but don't know how to save the key only, because I need only key, and the text is like a helper for the editors/creators. Should I use the rather choice or Lookup?

The second problem of Metadata that it can't be used in formulas... and I would like to use "KEY1" in some formulas... And now I find out that Lookup is either not supported in formulas... my God...

Answer (score 0):

Choice column with multiple selections, lookup column and managed metadata column are not supported in the SharePoint calculated column. The choice column with single selection is supported in the SharePoint Calculated column.

I suggest you use choice column then add value descriptions in the column description.